# How to get HTML tag from API response in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a response from Api like the following:

```
data: {
  id : 20,
  name : "Michael",
  content : "Today is <p>my special day in my life</p> thankyou"
}
```

and in react code as follows:

```
const dataMain = useselector((state) => state.main.data)

return (
  <>
    <div>
      <div className="name"><h2>{dataMain.name}</h2></div>
      <div className="the-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: dataMain.content></div>
    </div>
  </>
)
```

Result :

```
Michael,
Today is <p>my special day in my life</p> thankyou
```

The html P tag is still there, while I want it to disappear

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Answer (score -1):

When setting your content in **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** try `${dataMain.content}` otherwise set the value to state variable using `${}` syntax. This has worked for me on other compnents with HTML tags.

Example below:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
        content: null
    }
}

componentDidMount() {

    const payload = {};

    fetch("/example",{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .then((text) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                content: `${text}`
            });
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {!this.state.isLoaded &&
            <div className="text-info">
                Please wait...
            </div>
            }

            {this.state.isLoaded &&
            <div id="terms-content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}}/>
            }

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: `${dataMain.content}` — That syntax is for use inside template literals and there isn't one here.

Comment: Stackoverflow has stripped the template literal start + end from my post. I suggest OP tries to provide the value explicitly using a template literal syntax.

Comment: Well, that's pointless. The only effect that will have is to force `dataMain.content` to be a string, and passing it through that object to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` will do that anyway.